# Prolog is vs = with lists

Tags: prolog, resolution, unification

Why does this fail `L is [1,2,3,4]`, and this works: `L = [1,2,3]`?

But `L is 1`, and `L = 1` both work the same.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`is` should only be used when evaluating arithmetic operations on the right-hand side.
i.e.:

```
X is 1 + 2 + 3
```

`is/2` evaluates the right-hand structure as an arithmetic expression. If it is not a valid arithmetic expression or a number, `is/2` fails. Otherwise, the number to which the arithmetic expression evaluted is unified with the [presumably] unbound left-hand value.